# installing a Python package source tarball with pip

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, pip, distribute

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a Python source package that is installable via pip. I tried creating a test project with the setup.py file described on http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html
and a number of simple test files in the specified directories.

After creating a source tarball for the project named `dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz` with `python setup.py sdist`, I tried installing it in a virtualenv environment called `~/TEST` with 
`~/TEST/bin/pip install dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz`. Although pip didn't throw any error, it didn't seem to install the package:

```
$ ~/TEST/bin/pip install dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz 
Unpacking ./dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///home/lebedov/an_example_pypi_project/dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz

Cleaning up...
$ find ~/TEST -name "an_example*"
$
```

Note that I was able to install from the tarball using easy_install:

```
$ ~/TEST/bin/easy_install dist/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz 
Processing an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4.tar.gz
Running an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-tfXxeW/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-N2QY_N
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding an-example-pypi-project 0.0.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/lebedov/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for an-example-pypi-project==0.0.4
Finished processing dependencies for an-example-pypi-project==0.0.4
$ find ~/TEST/ -name "an_example*"                                  
/home/lebedov/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/an_example_pypi_project-0.0.4-py2.7.egg
```

Am I neglecting to configure something in the package in order to make it installable with pip? I'm using Python 2.7.2, distribute 0.6.21, virtualenv 1.7, and pip 1.0.2.

Comment: The problem seems to arise only when I invoke pip while the current directory is that which contains the source of the project. It appears that the presence of the .egg-info subdirectory created after building the source distribution confuses pip. Not sure if this is a bug - I'll ask the pip developers.

Comment: For future reference, here is the inquiry: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/414

Comment: This works for my project, and I have an .egg-info as well. Did you have a look at your directories using `tree`?

Comment: +1 for the bug report on github, which has specific steps to reproduce

Answer (score 6):

The bug report you posted on github had excellent instructions to reproduce. (I commented on the ticket and copied the response here.)

I followed those instructions to the letter using those exact versions of the packages you listed and still can't reproduce this issue.

Here's my output from `pip install --verbose` for the command in question:

```
Unpacking ./dist/anyjson-0.3.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///home/david/projects/anyjson-0.3.1/dist/anyjson-0.3.1.tar.gz
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/anyjson.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Installing collected packages: anyjson
  Running setup.py install for anyjson
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/anyjson
    copying anyjson/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/anyjson
    running install_lib
    creating /tmp/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anyjson
    copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/anyjson/__init__.py -> /tmp/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anyjson
    byte-compiling /tmp/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anyjson/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing anyjson.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to anyjson.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to anyjson.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'anyjson.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'anyjson.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying anyjson.egg-info to /tmp/TEST/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anyjson-0.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/tmp/pip-gvBT02-record/install-record.txt'
Successfully installed anyjson
Cleaning up...
```

Maybe you could add `--verbose` to your pip install command and post the output for comparison?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I commented out PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE in my .bashrc file, logged out, logged in, started my virtual environment and pip install worked fine.